# Query remaining quota for Google/Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to pro grammatically query remaining quota for the day through the Google/Youtube API?

Comment: i get the same question, if i can not find the answer in a short time, i will parse the API console HTML....

Comment: Submitted this issue against the sample YT API repository, to see if there would be a way: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/issues/236